# How to define CSS style without making it global in React Form?

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, rest, frontend

Today, I am working in making a landing page of my own startup company (I am a Data Scientist not Frontend-Dev). My overall folder configuration is like this below

```
/src
├── pages
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── 404.js
├── containers
│   ├── contactform
│       ├── index.js
│       ├── styles.js
│       ├── errorMessage.js
```

I stumbled upon making a React Form with code shown below (`/src/containers/contactform/index.js`). The function `ContactForm` is exported to `/src/pages/index.js`

```
import React from "react";
// import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import ErrorMessage from "./errorMessage";
import "./styles.css";

function ContactForm() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    errors,
    // setError,
    // clearError,
    formState: { isSubmitting }
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => {
    // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      
    fetch("https://myapi.com/sendmessage", {
              method: 'post',
              headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(data)
            })

    
  };


  return (
    <form id="form" className="contact" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <h1 id="contactus" className="contactheader">Contact Us - We will reach you</h1>
      <label className="contactlabel">First Name:</label>
      <input className="contactinput" name="firstname" ref={register({ required: true })} />
      <ErrorMessage error={errors.firstName} />

      <label className="contactlabel">Last Name:</label>
      <input className="contactinput" name="lastname" ref={register({ required: true, minLength: 2 })} />
      <ErrorMessage error={errors.firstName} />

      <label className="contactlabel">Email</label>
      <input className="contactinput" 
        name="email"
        ref={register({ required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i })}
      />
      <ErrorMessage error={errors.email} />

      <label className="contactlabel">Phone / Whatsapp</label>
      <input className="contactinput" name="phone" ref={register({ required: false })} />
      <ErrorMessage error={errors.phone} />

      <label className="contactlabel">Tell Us About your Current Need</label>
      <textarea className="contacttextarea" name="message" ref={register} />

      <input className="contactinput" disabled={isSubmitting} type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

// const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
// ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);


export default ContactForm;
```

with `/src/containers/contactform/styles.css` shown below

```
/* body {
  background: white;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
} */

form.contact {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1.contactheader {
  font-weight: 100;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(79, 98, 148);
}

/* .form {
  background: #0e101c;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
} */

p.errormessage {
  color: #bf1650;
}

p.errormessage::before {
  display: inline;
  content: "⚠ ";
}

input.contactinput {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

label.contactlabel {
  line-height: 2;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

button[type="submit"].contactinput,
input[type="submit"].contactinput {
  background: #ec5990;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

button[type="submit"].contactinput:hover,
input[type="submit"].contactinput:hover {
  background: #bf1650;
}

button[type="submit"].contactinput:active,
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="submit"].contactinput:active {
  transition: 0.3s all;
  transform: translateY(3px);
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

input:disabled {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

input[type="button"]:hover {
  transition: 0.3s all;
}

button[type="submit"].contactinput,
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"].contactinput {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.contact {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button[type="button"] {
  display: block;
  appearance: none;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

/* hr {
  margin-top: 30px;
} */

button[type="button"] {
  display: block;
  appearance: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

textarea.contacttextarea,
input {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid F5EEFF;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

I want to make my `/src/containers/contactform/style.css` only works in my `/src/containers/contactform/index.js` not globally alter my main landing page. I have gone so far such as adding `className` to each of the elements, but when it comes to `button` element, it alters most of my landing page button. The thing I don't understand is I can't find any `<button>` element inside the `/src/containers/contactform/index.js`. I assume that the `<button>` element is implicitly embedded inside the `<form>`. Therefore, when it comes to making it locally working only to my js file specifically on the `<button>` form, I can't find a way to change the button only in my contactform.

Comment: Inside your contactform/style.css, can you try removing the class name after button declarations? For example: `button[type="submit"].contactinput` to `button[type="submit"]`. You won't need to declare the class name there since you are using it only with `contactform/index.js`

Comment: @MarkBurns sorry, I have updated my question by adding folders configuration.. It doesn't work like I am expecting by not declaring the `className`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can put index.js and styles.css in same folder as subfolder of src or public. Then i assume that other files will not able to reach that css features from styles.css by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is by definition of how CSS works.

CSS applies to the whole DOM - that's the nature of CSS. Once you've imported it somewhere in your code, it applies to the entire page if it matches the classes because default behaviour is to import into global space. Importing CSS simply includes that CSS in your output css file (or inline in your JS file if configured as such).

There are some workarounds to make css *locally* as you want:

. [CSS Modules](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/)

. [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs)

*This [article](https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822) could be useful to you.